# Change layer properties

Tags: arcobjects, c#, layers

How can I edit name of lines of layer in ArcMap from Visual Studio C#? E.g., change **STR_NAME** = "Pushkin street" to **STREET** = "Pushkin street"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, what is STR_NAME AND STREET (are these database column names for changing a definition query)?  What do you mean by "lines of layer"?

Comment: If you're editing data or fields, then it's the feature class you're editing, not the layer. The layer simply points to the source data. As M.D. said below, you'll have to create a new field, copy the data, and delete the old one.

Comment: For example, I created an add-in, a custom tool which only operates with exact layer. But it has no idea, how layer and its db columns will be named. So I desided create a options class and window, where user can set settings. Maybe renaming fields in database is a little overhead, but I research all variants.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to rename the field STR_NAME to STREET, ArcObjects does not allow you to do that.  You will have to create the field STREET, copy the data from STR_NAME into it, then delete STR_NAME.